# What is `deployment.apps` in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am surprised that nobody has yet asked this, but what exactly is `deployment.apps`?

I see it often in commands e.g

```
kubectl rollout pause deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
```

or even used interchangably for the `deployments` keyword:
`kubectl get deployments`= `kubectl get deployment.apps`

I do not understand what it indicates though. Even in [K8s official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), they just take for granted that the reader understands the term.

Could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kubernetes API has its different resources (e.g. Pods, Deployments, Ingress) grouped in what they call "[api groups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups)" and in the notation `deployment.apps` - "[deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/deployment-v1/)" is the resource name and the "apps" is the api group name.

Also see the motivation for [API groups](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/a8d041d470d8b72f8a7fb4e8661ccda16b6b4c0f/contributors/design-proposals/api-machinery/api-group.md)